# jQuery Animation adjustments

Tags: javascript

For the jQuery function `.animate()` other than setting the interval timer, is there a way to adjust where the animation happens or height and width of the animation?

Answer (score 0):

The styles parameters can be used to specify the CSS properties/values to animate. You can animate with a ton of different properties, borders, margins, etc.